# Select data not in the date range between two dates

Tags: sql, date, validation, date-range

I have a table Named "leaves" and it holds data like this

[image]

what is the query if I want to select dates in the date range between two dates "from_date" and "to_date" in the "leaves" table?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  What have you tried?  What is the issue?

Comment: I want to get users not on leave between those 2 dates

Comment: public function bookAppointment($from_date,$to_date) {
        $con = $GLOBALS['con'];
        $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_role='3' "
                . "AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM leaves "
                . "WHERE leave_status ='1' "
                . "AND ($from_date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) "
                . "OR ($to_date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) "
                . "OR ($from_date <= from_date AND $to_date >= to_date))";
        $result = $con->query($sql) or die($sql);
        return $result;
        }

Comment: . . You should include sample data and desired results to clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more detail ( sample data and desired  output) but If I understand correctly this is what you need to do :

```
select user_id
from leaves
where 
 from_date >= $from_date
 and to_date <= $to_date 
 and $from_date < = $to_date
```